# How to replace an element in doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I have three same type linked list nodes, schcurr, search and schtemp.However only the search has links. schcurr and schtemp are not linked. I use search to find the place I want to put schcurr and I use schtemp just to help me for keeping links. 
If the following conditions hold, schcurr dominates search. So, I want to replace search with schcurr. Search is already in the list and schcurr is not connected to anything yet.

I put the related part of the code as follows but I am stucked there:(

P.S: TC1 is int and WF1 is float and they are not NULL.

```
if(schcurr.TC1==search.TC1)
    {
       if(schcurr.WF1>search.WF1)
           {                  
               //schcurr dominates search.
               schcurr.next=seach.next;
               schcurr.prev=seach.prev; 
            }
      }
```

Now I need to correct the search.prev's next and search.next's prev. 
I guess I can't set search.prev.next=schcurr; and seach.next.prev=schcurr; can I?

Any help is appreciated.

For information definition of the nodes:

```
struct schedules{
float WF1;
int TC1;    
schedules *prev;
schedules *next;
            };
struct schedules *sch;
struct schedules *head;
struct schedules *tail;
struct schedules *schtemp;
struct schedules *search;
```

Comment: That's not the beginning. The beginning would be the definition of the type of schcurr and search, then the code before the `if`.

Comment: Sure that is not the beginning of whole code, I wanted to keep it simple and put only the related part. Because the remaining is a mess since I am no professional. I added definitions but before if is mess and too many lines.

Comment: "schcurr, search and schtemp" makes it *three* list nodes, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your doubly linked list is correct, in that you can traverse both ways from your search node (both prev and next), then you can do exactly what you said.

```
search.prev.next = schcurr;
search.next.prev = schurr;
```

Edit: You need to do null checks if you do this, however. Since `search.prev`, for example, could point to null if you're at the head of your linked list already. Similarly, if you're at the end of your linked list, `search.next` would be null, so if you do `search.next.prev = something`, you would effectively be doing `null.next = something` and be in violation.

Comment: you only shown a small part of what needs to be done. the links of `schcurr` should then be updated to splice it in, and then the links inside `search` to cut it out.

Comment: He wrote that he wanted to replace it, so there's no need to replace the links of schcurr. In fact, based on what I interpreted, you should be freeing the memory of schcurr instead.

Comment: Although I agree that he doesn't have enough context. Is he traversing two linked lists in parallel? If so, and he wants to effectively swap the nodes between the two lists, then I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: "to replace search with schcurr" the OP said. meaning, take the node `search` out of a list, and put the node `schcurr` in its place - *in the list in which `search` was*.

Comment: @TimoteeTheCodeMonkee is right. schcurr does not have links initially.  Since I replace search with schcurr, should not I free the memory of search?

Comment: You don't need to free the memory if you never used `malloc` to allocate it. I don't know the context of what you're doing (i.e. is it global/local variable, etc). If you're going to use it again, however, you're likely not going to need to free it yet.

Comment: Actually, judging by how you're using it, it looks like you just declared it locally within your function. If such is the case, there's no need to free it.

Comment: @user1887909 if you know who's right, why are you asking questions?.. your `schcurr` doesn't have links set initially, but they need to be updated for it to become a part of a list into which you are inserting it. And it is impossible for it to "not have links" because your said "the three are same-typed". The links are there, they are just not set at first, and must be set correctly to complete the insertion. After that, you should reset links inside `search` to NULL, to cut it out; and **only after that** you can start thinking of freeing its memory or not.

Comment: @user1887909 and BTW it is much simpler *here* to just swap the data inside those nodes, instead of fidgeting with the links which is always fraught with dangers.

Comment: @WillNess , You are right, but, I have much more data than I showed here :( And for your other comment I only meant he understood me correctly about replacing.And Thank you for your additional comment about links.

Comment: @user1887909 yes, if your data is big and plenty, it's easier to splice the node in. Just as long as you're extra tidy about it. :)

Comment: @WillNess, If I use C++ compiler in code blocks does it save me from resetting links and freeing memory?

Comment: @user1887909 depends on how you've written your Node's destructor.

Comment: @WillNess, I did not:( I use GNU GCC and it seems it does not have garbage collector. I guess I need to free memory of every unnecessary node manually. For example in here, I guess I should set schtemp to the memory of dominated node and then free it. For both C and C++ compiler. Am I right?

Comment: @user1887909 c++ destructors are not related to garbage collection. Destructors may contain calls to `free()` or `delete`.

Comment: @WillNess, I am using malloc at the beginning and I am going to use free() to free that memory.